# When I'm validating in my angular app I'm facing No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AbstractControl[] Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I'm validating in my angular app I'm facing this error:

```
src/app/register/register.component.ts:45:39 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl[] | { [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AbstractControl[] | { [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.

45             return control?.value === control?.parent?.controls[matchTo].value ? null : {isMatching: true}
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is the method the error is coming from:

```
matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {

   return (control: AbstractControl) => {

        return control?.value === control?.parent?.controls[matchTo].value ? null : {isMatching: true}
       }
    

}
```

I'm just starting angular and TypeScript and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You have to define what kind of index type the object has. In your case it is a string based index.

```
matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        return control.value === (control?.parent?.controls as { [key: string]: AbstractControl })[matchTo].value ? null : { isMatching: true };
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can disable tslint rule check use /* tslint:disable-next-line */

Comment: the error is gone but the validation in my template is not working

Comment: Maybe you can debugger you code and to see if there have isMatching apply to that control or not.

Comment: facing this at the console  core.js:6006 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at register.component.ts:46....  and ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    }); ....

Comment: here is where i initilaize the form  initializeForm(){

    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('hello', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(8)]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.matchValues('password')]),

    })
  }

Comment: You got the undefined error as you are not check the parent && parent.controls exists or not, since the Validation fn will be extecuted many times as Angular way. I just create a demo for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t6kmze?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

i just ignored the line using // @ts-ignore and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here the index isn't string. it is a number.
then the answer is:

```
 matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const controls = control?.parent?.controls as { [key: string]: AbstractControl; };
      let matchToControl = null;
      if (controls) matchToControl = controls[matchTo];
      return control?.value === matchToControl?.value
        ? null : { isMatching: true }
    }
  }
```